# Suggestions for concise index handling in circular buffer

Tags: c, c99, sequence-points

I've implemented a circular buffer, and I would like a concise means of updating the buffer pointer while properly handling the wrap-around.

Assuming an array of size 10, my first response was something like:

```
size_t ptr = 0;  
// do some work...
p = ++p % 10;
```

Static analysis, as well as *gcc -Wall -Wextra*, rightly slapped my wrist for unspecified behavior due to a sequence point violation.  The obvious fix is something like:

```
p++;
p %= 10;
```

However, I was looking for something more concise, (i.e., a one-liner) to "encapsulate" this operation.  Suggestions? Other than **p++; p%= 10;** :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p = (p + 1) % N;
```

or to avoid the modulo:

```
p = ((N-1) == p) ? 0 : (p+1);
```

Comment: Heh, "p = (p + 1) % N" it is.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `p++; p%=10;`, I believe using the comma operator as in `p++, p%=10;` better qualifies as a "one-liner". You can use it in a macro or in the body of a loop or if/else statement without braces, and it evaluates to the resulting value of `p`.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered `++p %= 10;`

Comment: ++p is not modifiable in `C`. Don't know about `C++` or `Java` (question is not tagged with these languages)

Comment: Ah right. I just checked and it isn't modifiable in C. Another place where I've gotten tripped up in the differences between the languages.